# Server-Side NAT changing both source and dest adress: possible?

Tags: iptables

I have a typical LAN with `192.168.2.x` adresses. I'd like to expose a number of services on **different** hosts via a wireguard VPN.

Wireguard server is not running on my publicly acessible router, but on a more powerfull machine configured as exposed host. Wireguard is currently configured to use `10.0.0.x` adresses, with the server using `10.0.0.1`.

The client sucessfully connects to my VPN server, uses IP `10.0.0.2` and tries to reach services on `10.0.0.1`. Based on the port, I tried to use (server side) DNAT to forward packets to (e.g.) `192.168.2.1`. This basically works, using tcpdump I can see that packets are send with src `10.0.0.2` and dst `192.168.2.1`, so obviously they reach the correct host.

However, the `10.0.0.x` network is unknown everywhere except on my wireguard server (and I'd like not to change that), so `192.168.2.1` has no idea where to send answer packets. What I would need, I guess, is a server-side NAT variant changing both source **and** dest ip.

Is this possible?

To reduce confusion, I tried to create a simple overview:

```
VPN Host                                 LAN Service
IPs: 192.168.2.2, 10.0.0.1               192.168.2.1

Incoming Packet 
src: 10.0.0.2 dst: 10.0.0.1:666
masqueraded to:
src: 192.168.2.2 dst: 192.168.2.1:666

                                         receives packet
                                         src: 192.168.2.2 dst: 192.168.2.1:666

                                         sends answer packet
                                         src: 192.168.2.1:666 dst: 192.168.2.2

Receives answer packet:
src: 192.168.2.1:666 dst: 192.168.2.2
de-masqueraded to
src: 10.0.0.1:666 dst: 10.0.0.2
```

If this is not possible, do I have other options? Please note that eventually I want to forward packets to different local servers, based on the port.

Additional notes: The whole purpose of the VPN is exposing these services. The VPN network (`10.0.0.x`) should consist of my server exposing services from within it's LAN and remote clients using these services.

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own question: I could successfully setup combined DNAT and SNAT following Iain Brown's answer to this question:
https://superuser.com/questions/1286555/iptables-port-forwarding-with-internal-snat:

---

> After some experimenting, I think I've answered my question, so I
>   should post it here in case anyone else finds it useful. Yes, it is
>   possible, and it's fairly simple, just a matter of getting the right
>   combination of addresses and ports.
>
> Comments from my script:
>
> ```
> # summary:
> # allow forwarding *to* destination ip:port
> # allow forwarding *from* destination ip:port
> # nat packets identified by arrival at external IP / port to have
> #  *destination* internal ip:port
> # nat packets identified by arrival at internal IP / port to have
> #  *source* internal network IP of gateway machine
> ```
>
> For the example in the question:
>
> ```
> # allow inbound and outbound forwarding
> iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp -d 192.168.2.10 --dport 54321 -j ACCEPT
> iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp -s 192.168.2.10 --sport 54321 -j ACCEPT
>
> # route packets arriving at external IP/port to LAN machine
> iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat -p tcp -d 1.2.3.4 --dport 12345 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.2.10:54321
> # rewrite packets going to LAN machine (identified by address/port)
> # to originate from gateway's internal address
> iptables -A POSTROUTING -t nat -p tcp -d 192.168.2.10 --dport 54321 -j SNAT --to-source 192.168.2.5
> ```
>
> The actual script, since this should be easier to apply directly:
>
> ```
> # EXTIP = external IP of gateway (1.2.3.4)
> # EPORT = external port (12345)
> # DIP   = destination IP in local network (192.168.2.10)
> # DPORT = destination port (54321)
> # INTIP = internal IP of gateway (192.168.2.5)
>
> iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp -d $DIP --dport $DPORT -j ACCEPT
> iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp -s $DIP --sport $DPORT -j ACCEPT
>
> iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat -p tcp -d $EXTIP --dport $EPORT -j DNAT --to-destination $DIP:$DPORT
> iptables -A POSTROUTING -t nat -p tcp -d $DIP --dport $DPORT -j SNAT --to-source $INTIP
> ```